# How to insert new element at position: n in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slide with 7 items (7 div).

I want to add a new button after `div` have position 3.

Source:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
```

Like this:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<button>Click me</button>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
```

Have any method to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: you can the array of divs using `$('div')`, get the index you want then insert it using the function `after()` (jquery)

Comment: [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children), [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

Comment: If you intend to use jQuery in a general sense, why not spend half an hour browsing through the [list of jQuery methods](http://api.jquery.com/)? (One of the methods you need for your current problem is only fourth in the list.)

Comment: Thanks, @A.Lau and Ryan, nnnnnn. I don't have experience with Javascript before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("div").eq(2).after("<button>click</button>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
```

1. Use [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get third div

   > Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.
2. Use [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to append after div 3

   > Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: Thanks, @guradio. You awesome!

Comment: @vanloc glad to help mate happy coding :)

Comment: @vanloc Hey man I posted a solution too but that use of eq is really cool.  I have never seen it before.  Thanks for teaching me something new too!

Comment: Me too. Cool answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use vanilla Javascript, try doing the following. I am going to assume your `<div>`'s are nested within another HTML element:

```
<div id="some-id">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var btnText = document.createTextNode("Click me");
    btn.appendChild(btnText);

    var divs = document.getElementById("some-id");
    divs.insertBefore(btn, divs.childNodes[3]);
</script>
```

You will need to do some extra work to program the button etc.

Comment: It's working don't need jQuery or anything. Thanks for that.

Comment: No problem champ.

Answer (score 1):

You can give id's to all the divs, as:

```
<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
<div id="div4">4</div>
<div id="div5">5</div>
<div id="div6">6</div>
<div id="div7">7</div>
```

And then you can write following in jquery:

```
$("#div3").insertAfter("<button>Click me</button>");
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: `$(x).insertAfter(y)` will insert `x` after `y`, the opposite of what you need here.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can do this like so.

```
var divs = jQuery("div");
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.value = "Click Me";
jQuery(jQuery(divs).get(3)).after(button);
```

This is the easiest way I have found to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML  element is a specific version of the  element used to create a clickable button with no default value. It has been superseded in HTML5 by the  element.
so to creates a new button input with the label 'Click me' type blow code between the div's.

also try this

Click me

Comment: Seem you don't have permission to insert new link because your account is new. Thanks for your answer.